# How to use adMob and (google map api)google play service together?

Tags: android, google-maps, admob, google-play-services

I have an app on the market with adMod banner, and now I am trying to add some Google Maps api to my application.

I know how to handle adMobs library or Google Maps api separately. But when I try to run the app with adMob and Google Maps api (Google Play service), it seems they have a collision or something like that. Or google-play-services.jar and GoogleAdMobAdsSdk.jar have the same class name for AdMob. Maybe due to that reason I am getting multiple .dex files.

My error on my console is:

trouble writing output: already prepared [2014-05-18 18:24:40 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode; [2014-05-18 18:24:40 - WorkC 3.0.9 actionBar] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;

I'm afraid it would be bad to my adMob as soon as I update the application version. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mobile Ads is now a part of Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/ads.html), hence a lot of class names are duplicated now. See the migration guide [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration).