# Error using both AdMob and Google-Map plugins together with Ionic

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, admob

I'm creating an Ionic app from scratch, on Windows 10, using the following instructions:

```
ionic start testIonic --v2
cd testIonic
ionic platform add android
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps
ionic plugin add cordova-admob
ionic run android
```

With those steps, I'm receiving the following errors at compilation:

[image: error when i compile]

Everything works fine if i only use one of the cordova plugins:

PS. I already tried doing the following with no success:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-admob
ionic plugin add admob
```

I've already seen both this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725887/how-to-use-admob-and-google-map-apigoogle-play-service-together) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709120/cordova-cli-admob-and-google-maps-plugins-conflict) but none of them seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41042556/1623180

You have to:

1.- Make sure you're running your application on an emulator with Google Play Services installed, in case you're testing your app on a physical device, this should not be the problem.

2.- Go to your SDK Manager (which you can access through Android Studio) and install the following packages: Android Support Repository, Library, Play Services and Google Repository.

3.- Go to project.properties on your ionic root folder, and update the versions both Maps and Admob are using.

To complete the last point you have to search for something like:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:<plugin-name>:9.2.0
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:<plugin-name>:9.2.0
```

And update them to use the same version, could be `+`,`9.20` or `9.8.0`, I'd recommend using the `+` indicator:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:<plugin-name>:+
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:<plugin-name>:+
```

Let us know if that solves your problem.